# How can i retrieve dynamic CRM online audit summary with CRM SDK?

Tags: dynamics-crm

I want to get a list of entities which are deleted recently. from audit summary view, we can see which entity is deleted. But how can I do it with CRM SDK(C# code)? Is it possible to write a query expression(with specified operation, date filter...) to query audit summary?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to retrieve the data change history using [RetrieveRecordChangeHistoryRequest Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.retrieverecordchangehistoryrequest.aspx)

This is a sample code:

```
// Retrieve the audit history for the account and display it.
RetrieveRecordChangeHistoryRequest changeRequest = new RetrieveRecordChangeHistoryRequest();
changeRequest.Target = new EntityReference(Account.EntityLogicalName, _newAccountId);

RetrieveRecordChangeHistoryResponse changeResponse =
(RetrieveRecordChangeHistoryResponse)_service.Execute(changeRequest);

AuditDetailCollection details = changeResponse.AuditDetailCollection;
```

[Sample: Audit entity data changes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309735.aspx) is an example on how you can enable and disable auditing on an entity and its attributes, retrieve the data change history of the audited entity, and delete the audit records.

Comment: In your code sample, we first need know the entity id(_newAccountId, here).  problem is how can we query this entity id from audit summary, i want a list of entities deleted and their entity ids.

Comment: What is the entity logical name of audit summary ?
As we need to fetch the user access records from CRM online.

Can anyone help ?